# ContourPlot3D that works in Mathematica 9 but not in 10

Tags: plotting

I have a code that works in Mathematica 9 but not in Mathematica 10 which is very annoying. I just get a blank plot in Mathematica 10 on Mac OSX El Capitan.

Below is the code:

```
h = x*z - y^2;
g =  Norm[{x, y, z}, 2];
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 
1},MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, h - g]},MeshStyle -> 
{{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {1},ContourStyle -> {{Orange}, {Red, Opacity[0.5]}}]
```

Anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: works well in V10.3/4 Win7

Comment: I am using Mac OSX El Capitan. I am getting a blank plot.

Comment: Works in version 10.4.1 under Win 10.

Comment: On Linux I'm getting blank plot unless I press to hold and rotate. This is a common occurrence with 3d plots on UNIX.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKalbat - what is the result when you run `$Version`?  I'm using El Capitan also, version 10.3.1 and it works.  I have a lot of memory so maybe that's the issue for you?

Comment: it is 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit). It is an old version. This is why I think. I will update now.

Comment: Is working fine on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)" on OS x 10.11.5 MacBook Pro mid 2012

Comment: Works fine on MM 10.4.1, OSX 10.10.5

Comment: "10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" works fine.

Comment: Works with Mathematica v10.4.1 with Mac OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

Comment: Thanks all for testing this code. I upgraded my Mathematica to 10.4.1 and the code is perfectly working now.